# Someone who enjoys statistics

Tags: single-word-requests, statistics

Is there a single word for someone who likes or loves to examine statistics?

Comment: Statisto-phile, statisto-philia?

Comment: This is a "sports fan"!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A *statistician* is one who collects and/or works with statistics. You are unlikely to find a single word in wide use for someone who enjoys consuming statistics as an amateur pastime, although people often coin such words as needed by appending *-[o]phile* or *-[o]holic* to the root word, or to a derivative of it: *statophile, statoholic*.

Comment: Thanks. _Statophile_ and _statoholic_ are probably the closest it can get to what I was looking for.

Comment: Be aware, however, that _statistician_ is a professional term (like _physicist, biologist, astronomer, psychologist,_ etc.), and should not be applied to anyone who does not have a professional qualification, occasionally under legal licensing laws. I.e, it doesn't apply to amateurs, unless it's prefixed with the word _amateur_.

Comment: Please note that *stato-* is a Greek prefix for *standing/resting/not moving*, so a 'statophile' might be a good, fancy word for a couch potato as well!

Comment: Also keep in mind that _-[o]holic_ tends to connote an overabundance of or an obsession with something bordering on dangerous (also addictions).

Answer (score 3):

The closest I can think of is a **number-cruncher**:

> a person or thing that performs a great many numerical calculations,
>   as a financial analyst, statistician, computer, or computer program.

More generic words for people who like math are **nerd** and **geek** or coined words like [mathophile](http://mathophilia.com/author/admin/).

Answer (score 3):

**[Quantophrenia](https://www.wordnik.com/words/quantophrenia)** n. Excessive reliance on or use of facts and figures that can be derived using statistical or mathematical procedures

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit more work-related than what you’re asking, but in a business context, someone who focuses on analysing things numerically is a *[quant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quant)*.

Answer (score 1):

In UK slang: [**Statto**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=statto)!

[image]**

> Angus Loughran... rose to fame as "Statto", the resident statistician on the BBC Two television show Fantasy Football League. Clad in a dressing gown and pyjamas, he would stand in the corner of the set and provide facts and figures on each of the guests' fantasy football teams, while being made fun of by hosts Frank Skinner and David Baddiel.

Comment: And an American equivalent is something like "stats geek."

Comment: @TomAu I think that's more an English language description than it is 'American slang'...

Comment: @OllieFord: I always think of nerd and geek as quite American words, but that might just be because I watched *Saved by the Bell* too much (i.e. at all) as a youth. “Boffin” was the equivalent UK term for “geek” or “nerd” in my school days.

Comment: Haha, I haven't heard that since middle school (we have them in my area) when 'dweeb' was also popular. Different connotations though, I would suggest 'boffin' can be used similarly to '-buff'.